# Would Apple approve an app that uses unmodified sample code from the iPhone developer center?

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

I'm writing a class that extends a UIScrollView to display a large tiled image, and I've realized that the TiledScrollView from Apple's ScrollViewSuite sample code does the same thing very well. Can I use their code, or do I have to write my own, even if it ends up heavily inspired by Apple's code?

If it makes a difference, I don't have any plans (at the moment) to monetize the app.

Comment: What license did they put on the sample code?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Apple or app approvals, and everything to do with acceptable usage as specified in the sample code's license.

Comment: Part of the license:
"...Apple grants you a personal, non-exclusive
 license, under Apple's copyrights in this original Apple software (the
 "Apple Software"), to use, reproduce, modify and redistribute the Apple
 Software, with or without modifications..."

I think that means I can use it in my app... right?

Comment: I see nothing in that short snippet that would prohibit use in your app.  Review the entire license, though, for information on other topics - attribution, other limitations, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically I would take the "I am not a lawyer" route, but Apple really is quite clear in their license. You can pretty well do whatever you want with it. You can certainly use it in your products in any of the ways you likely have in mind, and Apple encourages you to do so. The only restrictions they really have in there are standard BSD-style things: don't sue us, don't say you're part of Apple, and "if you redistribute the Apple Software in its entirety and 
 without modifications, you must retain this notice..." (so don't strip off their notice and put the source code on your web site and pretend you wrote it).

Apple's example code license is in the same realm with BSD and MIT. Very laid back; easy to comply with.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think they care. A lot of developers (myself included) include the Reachability sample in their code and it hasn't caused any rejections that I'm aware of.